# How to exclude weekends and holidays from finding the difference between two dates in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to find the difference between 2 dates where certain end dates are blank. I am need to exclude the weekends, as well as the holidays when calculating the dates. I also need to put into account the blank end_dates.

I have a data frame which looks like:

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2020 | 05-01-2020 |
| 30-10-2021 | NaT |
| 15-08-2019 | NaT |
| 29-06-2020 | 15-07-2020 |

The code for retrieving the holidays I wrote as the following:

```
df = read_excel(r'dates.xlsx')
df.head()
us_holidays = holidays.UnitesStates()
```

The following code works around the null values and it excludes the weekends

```
def business_days(start, end):
    mask = pd.notnull(start) & pd.notnull(end)
    start = start.values.astype('datetime64[D]')[mask]
    end = end.values.astype('datetime64[D]')[mask]
    holi = us_holidays.values.astype('datetime64[D]')[mask]
    result = np.empty(len(mask), dtype=float)
    result[mask] = np.busday_count(start, end, holidays= holi)
    result[~mask] = np.nan
    return result



df['count'] = business_days(df['start_date'], df['end_date'])
```

The error I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

How can I fix the following error?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the typo in your original code as well? `df[çount']`

Comment: No the I made an error writing the code here.

Comment: How do you want to the blank dates to be handeled? Replace it with today?

Comment: @SebastianB they are fine as blanks or they can be today's date, whichever one is the easiest to write. Thanks.

Comment: @Mbalenhle: If my answer solved your problem, please accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm not familiar with the holiday package. But holidays.UnitesStates() seems to return an object and not the needed
   list of dates. However you can create a list of holiday dates for a certain range of years.
2. I'm not sure why you get "NaT", ususally you get NaNs. But you can handle both.

One way to do it:

```
   import holidays
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   import datetime
   
   #Create Dummy DataFrame:
   df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['start_date','end_date'])
   df['start_date'] = np.array(["2020-01-01","2021-10-30","2019-08-15","2020-06-29"])
   df['end_date'] = np.array(["2020-01-05","NaT","NaT", "2020-07-15"])
   
   #Convert Columns to datetime
   df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
   df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'])
   
   #Convert DateTime to Date
   df['start_date'] = df['start_date'].dt.date
   df['end_date'] = df['end_date'].dt.date
   
   #Not sure why you get NaT when you read the file with pandas. So replace it with today:
   df = df.replace({'NaT': datetime.date.today()})
   #In case you get a NaN:
   df = df.fillna(datetime.date.today())
   
   #Get First and Last Year
   max_year = df.max().max().year
   min_year = df.min().min().year
   
   #holidays.US returns an object, so you have to create a list
   us_holidays = list()
   for date,name in sorted(holidays.US(years=list(range(min_year,max_year+1))).items()):
          us_holidays.append(date)
   
   start_dates = list(df['start_date'].values)
   end_dates = list(df['end_date'].values)
   
   df['count'] = np.busday_count(start_dates, end_dates, holidays = us_holidays)
```